# safe unique filename with no race condition

Tags: php

Is this a safe way to move uploaded file with respect to race conditions?

```
do { 
    $file = $path . "/" . uniqid() . '.' . $ext; 
    $fh = @fopen($file, 'x'); 
} while( ! $fh);
move_uploaded_file($src, $file);
```

**UPD** Besides learning other ways of solving the problem I would like to know if this code is subject to race conditions. AFAIU, fopen with 'x' mode and move_uploaded_file are atomic, so no collision could be possible.

On top of that and with regards to "uniqid will suffice", [several](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php#98232) [people](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php#97086) in [comments](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php#37762) to tempnam stated necessity of using fopen with 'x' mode to avoid race conditions. Do they overly paranoid? I think, having safer solution is better, if it doesn't make code significantly complex.

Comment: what race conditions? if you're worried about collisions, then don't generate random filenames. use a database auto_increment-type id field to generate a guaranteed unique filename.

Comment: Yes, I'm worried about collisions. The idea about using database auto_increment fields is interesting, but I'd prefer to know how to solve the problem using filesystem capabilities alone.

Comment: uniqid should be all you need.

Answer (score 1):

PHP's [tempnam](http://php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php) function guarantees the uniqueness. Or you can use a filename that is based on a microtimestamp (which won't work under MS-Windows...).

Comment: But tempnam limits you in what can be used as a filename. E.g., you can't specify extension.

Comment: Why that? You can concatenate any string with a leading dot (".") to the generated name. That does not make is less unique. Apart from that: what are such "file name extensions" good for on server side? Even on client side modern systems have better means to decide upon a files content as to look at funny three characters someone wrote at the end of the file name.

Comment: If I add extension to unique filename, resulting filename may already exist. Am I wrong?

Comment: Why then they changed behaviour in php 4.0.3? [tempnam](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php) now creates file "to avoid race condition". If I append something to tempnam-generated filename, I fall back to what was prior to php 4.0.3.

Comment: No you won't. It won't happen that the tempnam function gives you the same prefix a second time especially _because_ a file has been created. It serves as a lock for that unique prefix.

Comment: Ok, what are your statement about having the same prefix a second time is based on? File has been created with extension added, so no lock for that unique prefix exists.

Comment: No, the function itself creates a file named like the prefix before actually handing that name back to you. If you then add an extension to the name and create another file does not change a thing on what has happened before. The empty file named like the prefix still exists and blocks. True, you might have to cleanup that file too later, but that's just two lines of code and the zero byte length don't cost anything. But again: I see no reason to use such a "name extension", it is redundant information. What do you need it for?

Comment: Yes, I'd rather delete those empty files. Sure, it doesn't cost anything, but your solution is a little hacky. If I had written a script, which traverses the directory for some reason, I would have been forced to take into account this empty files. Not that it makes the code too complex, but I prefer to write code with no wtf's.

Comment: As to extensions, it seems safer, if web server provides client with proper content-type. Nginx marks files with no extension as application/octet-stream, for example. I assume, apache does the same. But anyway, thanks for the idea. You made me think about it. I need to check for how browsers treat such files.

Comment: You mean you have no index but just rely on files existing or not when they are requested? Ok, then you don't have the mimetype at hand when delivering the file. On the other hand, this is only a problem if you really allow direct http requests to the files. If you deliver them via a wrapper (some sort of script) you have no problem sending a specific mimetype header. In there you can specify that mimetype you get when asking the files mimetype from the system.

Comment: I have index.php, which handles all the requests for non-existent files. But what's so bad about allowing direct http downloads? It's rather good, because usually there is no point in implementing sending files over http. Sending files is responsibility of a web-server. But anyway, I may assign extension to a file on handling upload, and necessity for a wrapper disappears.

Comment: Direct http access to files certainly is easy to setup. However it does not offer any of the convenience of a managed download (script wrapped), like additional headers, fine grained response details like compression, archives-on-the-fly, expiration control, ... Oh, and: having the http server guess the mimetype by a file name extension is a little like sticking ones head into the sand, isn't it? ("let's hope there is html in that file named *.htm ...")

Comment: All the advantages you mentioned can be achived using http server settings alone. Except for when it depends on data stored in database. But either way, there is no need to send files manually. Http server's implementation is almost always superior to php's version. There are X-Accel-Redirect and X-Sendfile... And having the http server guess the mimetype by a filename extension is ok (in case of user uploaded files), if extension is assigned based on file's content.

Comment: You write "if extension is assigned based on file's content"... Well, you know, some people actually py purpose put a wrong file name extension to uploaded files. To trick other users, to pass stupid type allowance limits. In addition a single file name extension can be used by several mimetypes. So it is not clear by the name, what content actually is contained in the file. But if you are fine with a direct file based approach all is ok. Nothing against it. It is just that som many good reasons exist to finally get rid of that 80ish style of detecting a files content.

Comment: I meaned that if script, handling file uploads, assigns extension based on file's content, then all is ok, as long as allowed extensions unambiguously map to mime-types. In other words if we can trust file's extension, everything's fine. By the way, if files are to be downloaded by user, extensions are preferable, if we care about users.

Comment: I agree that for download a name extension makes sense. There are too many users still using MS-Windows with its strange mixture of behaviour: content based selection of app vs name extension based file handling. You have to specify a name for a file anyway if you send it during a download. Then you can also specify a name extension. I am surprised that you decide upon the mimetype in the upload script. I expected you to accept the extension the user specified during the upload... If you decide which name extension to use anyway inside a script, why is it preferable to do so during upload?!?

Comment: Because then http server may trust file extensions. And this may eliminate necessity of a wrapper script.

Comment: That way http server doesn't need to ask php for each file it's going to send to the client.