# file_exists on high load system

Tags: php

The code:

```
$tmp_file_path = '/path/to/tmp/file';

// move file from tmp dir
$new_file_path = '/path/to/new/location/file';
while(file_exists($new_file_path)){
  $new_file_path = $new_file_path . microtime(true);
  usleep(100000);
}

// HERE ANOTHER INSTANCE OF THIS SCRIPT COULD HAVE ALREADY TAKEN NEW NAME,
// $new_file_path
// BUT NEXT CALL TO rename function OVERWRITES IT WITH NEW CONTENT!

rename($tmp_file_path, $new_file_path ); //Attempts to rename oldname to newname,
// moving it between directories if necessary. If newname exists, it will be
// overwritten.
```

What solution is there in PHP to make `file_exists` function create a file, if it doesn't exist, like `touch` does, in one **atomic** operation?

Comment: could you use PHP's `exec("touch " . $new_file_path);` or is that off limits here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP has `tempnam` function:

```
// create a file with unique name in $new_file_path
$new_file_path = '/path/to/new/location';
$tmpfname = tempnam($new_file_path, "foo");
```

According to [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php):

> `tempnam` creates a file with a unique filename, with access permission set to
>   0600, in the specified directory. If the directory does not exist,
>   `tempnam()` may generate a file in the system's temporary directory, and
>   return the name of that.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php#98232 Says about non-atomic. Changelog of tempnam in 4.0.3 says they fixed race conditions. Fixed race conditions = really atomic, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, Fixed race conditions = really atomic. Look at discussion in the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13018787/safe-unique-filename-with-no-race-condition